# Is there a way to use JSDoc's @alias in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

Simplified version of my manually defined `.d.ts` file:

```
interface FooLikeInner<A, B> extends Foo<A, B> {}

declare global {
    export namespace FooPackage {
        // Foo comes from an external package and we are augmenting
        interface Foo<A, B> {}
        type FooLike<A, B> = FooLikeInner<A, B> & B;
    }
}
```

This works as intended, but I'd prefer to hide `FooLikeInner` from anyone downstream; the mouseover is likely to be confusing.

The only reason `FooLikeInner` exists is because `interface FooLike<A, B> extends Foo<A, B>, B {}` gave TS errors (`B could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object'`) and I didn't want to add a `// @ts-expect-error` (even though that seemed to have my intended behavior)

I discovered JSDoc has a helpful @alias tag, but it doesn't seem to do anything in Typescript (at least not within vscode), unfortunately: https://jsdoc.app/tags-alias.html

It's not the worst thing in the world that mouseover in vscode shows `FooLikeInner<A, B> & B`, but given the `.d.ts` file explicitly uses `FooLike` and *not* `FooLikeInner`, I don't want to confuse anyone else using my code if avoidable.